# AJAX with dataType JSON parse error on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

EDIT:
I have since switched everything over to mysqli. I had another script that did everything correctly in mysqli, but in my haste I copied a portion of someone else's without noticing it was done in mysql. Looks like this fixes that problem, thanks everyone! I have edited my code below so that it can be used as a resource for anyone who's fighting a similar problem.

I am having some trouble getting ajax to work on a godaddy shared hosting account. I've used it before on another sever without any trouble, so I'm thinking it's something odd about the godaddy server, though I'd be happy to be incorrect. I tried writing up this code in perl first but turns out godaddy doesn't support JSON.pm, so I switched over to php since that seems to be godaddy's language of choice. I'm still throwing an error at the ajax call.

Here's a toy version of each part. The only part of the HTML that's pertinent is the call to overlay.js and the test id secton to show that jQuery is working.

The HTML below calls overlay.js:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Carl Thomas Edwards</title>
  <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/overlay.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="main">
  <p>
      <span id="test">0</span> match(es) found.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that the jQuery part is working because I've tested using jQuery DOM selection and it works (the test id gets modified as expected). Basically all that should happen if everything is working is an alert that says "FUNCTIONAL". However, I always get an error that says:

```
Failed to perform AJAX call! textStatus: (parsererror) and errorThrown: (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)
```

I think that the error has to do with godaddy doing something oddly with json, but I could be wrong. When I comment out the dataType: 'json' line the alert does say functional. I'm not sure where a "<" would be coming from if that's actually the problem?

overlay.js

```
$(function() {
  $('#test').text( "text yes?" );

  $.ajax({
    url: 'overlay.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("FUNCTIONAL");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Failed to perform AJAX call! textStatus: (" + textStatus +
              ") and errorThrown: (" + errorThrown + ")");
    }
  });
});
```

The ajax call, according to Chrome Developer Tools, runs overlay.php without any errors. I know that the database connection I have works as it has been tested elsewhere. I know that my query works as it has been tested on the server in SSH. I don't think there are likely any errors in this file, but again, I'm open to suggestion since this is driving me nuts.

overlay.php

```
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
  if(mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $qry = "
    SELECT paint_id, paint_name, paint_date, paint_media, paint_dim, paint_file 
    FROM paintings
    WHERE paint_id = '1'
  ";

  $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);    

  echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

The URL for the full code is: http://www.carlthomasedwards.com/painting2.php

I have enabled json in my php.ini file on godaddy. I also contacted them for support and the guy was completely clueless. Is there something else special that needs to be done to get ajax calls working on godaddy? Why is the error saying a "<" symbol is showing up in the json? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you are getting some kind of mysql error `mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line`

Comment: You got some error messages `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />...
null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP script you're opening the DB connection as a `mysqli` resource, but attempting to query it as a `mysql` resource. You can't mix the two sets of calls. Use `mysqli` and drop `mysql` since the latter is deprecated.

Mixing the calls this way is likely to cause your later `mysql` code to fail and give an error message which you aren't checking for or handling.

If the error message is being returned raw instead of the expected JSON result you'll get exactly the sort of error message from Javascript that you're seeing.

**[edit]**

I took a look at your site. This is what is being returned by your ajax call:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/78/11658278/html/overlay.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
null
```

Comment: Arg I copied the end of someone else's php file to do that bit and forgot to check if it was mysqli or mysql. I have it done in mysqli elsewhere (which is why it was half and half), should have just written myself >.<. Great catch! So that I might help myself in the future, what tool are you using to pull down those error messages? I've looked all over Chrome Developer Tools, but can't find comparable messages.

Comment: @sage88 I use Firebug and Firefox for development and debugging. FB has a handy Net tab that tracks all network traffic in and out.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I've been considering switching to developing there as it is, now I'm convinced it's way better. Thanks again!